# rails 4 form_for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, form-for

I am using `<%= form_for @invoice, url: {action: :pay} do |f| %>` but the form is sent to the update action instead of the "pay" action I defined in the controller. What am I missing?

Comment: are you using resources route?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that. I defined `post 'invoices/:id' => 'invoices#pay'`

Comment: can you show me your routes?

Comment: get 'tasks/current' => 'tasks#current'
    post 'invoices/:id' => 'invoices#pay'
    post 'tasks/:id' => 'tasks#complete'
    resources :clients
    resources :payees
    resources :tasks do
      resources :jobs
    end
    resources :invoices do
      resources :clients
      resources :payees
      resources :tasks
    end

Comment: try this `url: {action: "pay"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have param `:id` in your route, and you should assign a param to `id` in your form action, try this

```
<%= form_for @invoice, url: {action: "pay", params: {id: @invoice.id}} %>
```

Or you can use a `path`

```
<%= form_for @invoice, url: for_pay_path(@invoice) %>
```

`for_pay_path` change to path of `pay` action, you can see on ouput of `rake routes`